# Ubuntu 12.04-2 on Apple Xserv early 2008

Tags: system-installation, graphics, uefi, apple, xserver

I have at work several xserv doing nothing, and I want to install Ubuntu. I booted from the CD choose Efi and edited the kernel option to add nomodeset so it boots normally.

Then the kernel loaded fine until it hit the Ubuntu GUI installer which gave me unreadable
Screen and colors, however I can see the mouse moving and if I hit enter on keyboard the installer jumps to other page in the installation but not readable at all. I tried kernel
Options: video=vesa and other video modes
But still same! any ideas regarding this?

Screen gets like this:

[image]

Another one:

[image]

Here is a youtube video of what happens:
If I do not add nomodeset the kernel will load halfway thru and freezes at certain point. If I add nomodeset all works fine except the graphics, even on ubuntu server which suppose to be fully cli mode.

[Ubuntu Server 12.10 x64 - Xserv 2,1 Early 2008](http://youtu.be/pmJRlc3DvMA)

Answer (score 0):

Try `nomodeset` as a kernel option.

If that fails, try a BIOS-mode boot, if your model supports that (I'm not sure if Apple server models do).

Comment: As I said, I am using nomodeset to boot the kernel. But gets screwes on the graphical installer...

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing looks very much like a video driver issue. If you have the option when booting from the CD, skip the Graphical Install and use the command line instead. That may let you install Ubuntu and the proper video drivers load during the installation process.

The other possible issue that pops to mind is, that if the Xserve is using an adapter to connect the monitor (which is what I recall from the Intel Xserves that I used) is that the adapter is at fault. If you have another adapter, switch them out and try again.

Comment: Yes it used a small adapter to take the screen vga cable. But I dont think its faulty because we had installed Mac OsX on the xserv before... But I will try to see if there is an option to go text mode install because the grub2 menu is different then normal one since Xservs boots in efi mode.

Comment: I brought up the adapter because I have seen situations where adapters would be marginally faulty and function on one machine but not another.  The option to do a graphical install is on the first screen when booting from the CD IIRC.

Comment: Hi Again, replacing quiet splash with text does not help. Now trying to install ubuntu server which in deed is a text based installation works, but facing problems while detecting hardware. Its frustrating...

Comment: If it will boot from the Server install CD and show text properly, there's a fair chance the install will work. I would recommend using the 12.04 LTS version of Server

Comment: I have tried 12.10 server and still check up the youtube video with nomodeset. The video is in the 1st thread.

Comment: Looked at the video and did some researching for you. Look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xserve2-1 for some tips on getting Ubuntu to work on an Xserve.

Comment: looks like I need to get older ubuntu version maybe.

Comment: Not sure if that would be any better, but worth a shot. I'd try Lucid that can be downloaded here http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

Comment: I am now accessing the server thru SSH which works fine. I will check if I can install the ATI Radeon X1300 driver...

Comment: Updates! I installed

Comment: After the ssh, I installed xorg-driver-fglrx and xserver-xorg-video-radeon and rebooted with nomodeset, solved the console mode graphic problem. I can see everything clear, now I am installing the GUI apt-get install ubuntu-desktop to see if it works thru.

Comment: Now after installing the ubuntu-desktop it does not connect to the xserver so xserver-xorg does not start. I removed fglrx and here is a paste of my xorg.log   http://pastebin.com/y1zMVGYH

Comment: I would wonder what repository your apt-get for Desktop pulled from. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine to make sure that you only have the Lucid repos listed. In the meantime, remove Desktop with `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` and reinstall fglrx.

Comment: No, I didn't get lucid installed. I am still on 12.10 installed and ubuntu-desktop from server 12.10.

Comment: I would still roll back and uninstall Desktop and restore fglrx to have a "working" system. You may have to install a custom device driver for the onboard video in the Xserve. The Xserves used the ATI Radeon X1300 video chipset.

Comment: Yes i rolled back and installed fglrx and i have a working ubuntu server console, but still need the correct driver for the Ati Radeon x1300 i will search for it and compile it for the kernel.

Comment: I removed the nomodeset and updated grub and rebooted, what was new is that it booted the Grub with the colored Menu and booted the system without a problem till it went to the console mode. Now logging in and typing: startx

gives this error in the xorg log.

http://pastebin.com/kw2pF3D3

And here is the output of dmesg:

http://pastebin.com/we5LsqCi

Thanks!

Comment: Updates,

I created an xorg.conf file and rebooted! the Lightdm screen came up!! Now I have a running X :) FINALLY! however when I login it quickly blink and shows back the lightdm login. 
I went in to console and typed: startx, it opened Gnome desktop only no menus! I can only right click and create folder on the desktop.

*** Reminder that this is an ubuntu-server 12.10 and after I installed it, I did the apt-get install ubuntu-desktop. (555MB)

Is there anything else related to ubuntu-desktop to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying there is no Launcher sidebar, or nothing in the top menu bar? Or neither?

Comment: Exactly just the desktop without any sidebar taskbars...

Comment: Not sure where to point you from here. Gnome elements aren't loading for some reason..?

Comment: I did this: sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity

unity --reset

unity --replace

sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-session
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install indicator-application indicator-session 
sudo apt-get install indicator-power indicator-sound